# Applescript : count Length

Tags: applescript

I created a code which count the length of a variable and take action regarding the length.

It's work well except when I have a variable in this format :

> "00108030-00045C9E2638502E"

1: the count is returning 8 and not 25
2: I have the error :

> "Can’t make 8 into type boolean." number -1700 from 8 to boolean"

Here is a preview of my code :
"

```
set theGUIDLength to (get length of (GUID as text))
if theGUIDLength is equal to 25 or 8 then
--
end if
```

"

Comment: - my script work if I set if theGUIDLength is equal to 8 then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
if theGUIDLength = 25 or theGUIDLength = 8 then
## do code
end if
```

Comment: Yes thank you, any idea why the result is 8 and not 25 though? it's stop the count after "-"

Comment: Not without testing exactly sorry on phone. I would modify how you're going about it because it looks like you're comparing text VS an integer

Comment: I actually found the issue, before I have "set [serialNumber, GUID] to the words of myClipboard" so that the issue. anyway thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a cleaner way to do this:

```
if theGUIDLength is in {25, 8} then
## do code
end if
```